# Is it possible to have a nested react-navigation controlling a portion of the screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to React Navigation and want to use it to control navigation across several screens which all fill the whole viewport, let's call them A, B and C.

One of these screens (B) needs to have several views which can be navigated between, let's call then B1, B2 and B3, but I want them to all have the same header and footer which stays exactly where it is and doesn't get re-instantiated.

So, when on screen B the portion in the middle needs to slide between 'screens' like a carousel (almost like a tab system without the tabs) and the whole thing could be transitioned back to A or C at any moment, destroying the sub-screens.

As far as I can tell from the docs there can only be one props.navigation in the app (using withComponent for example) So I don't think I can just use createStackNavigator on the main view then use it again to create another stack when on screen B.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.